# Best practices for Entity Framework Code First deployment

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-deployment, asp.net-mvc-5

I am creating an ASP.Net MVC 5 website with EF Code First. Although I have written a lot of code and have worked in this business for a long time, I have no experience in deploying a managed website. It seems to me that the goal of EF Code First approach is to create a DB that just **works** and it's no good for *real world* deployment.

If that's the case, I was wondering if there is a conference talk, tutorial or other type of resource that I can use to learn about best practices for this purpose. Especially learning how to create a secure and sophisticated database from the scheme of my existing one.

I've searched around and read a lot of opinions about this and got a little confused. Since I'm using MVC 5, I think there are some *old* and some *new* ways to do this so I'm asking your advice to pick the best method that works for me.

Comment: this is a pretty big question, but I can tell you that I was where you are now a couple of years back and I just jumped in head first - my instinct is to tell you to start with a good SQL Server book and do model first development to start with, as I tend to agree that code first is stronger for prototyping/rapid development than product deployment.. and after a couple of years i'm still far from being an expert

Comment: Why do you think that the DB is no good for real world deployment. There is absolutely no difference between the database it creates and the one you create. Especially if you are using migrations. You can add any indexes by adding custom code to the migration.

Comment: I didn't say "no good" - just from a starting point of getting your head around all the issues of deploying a production website, I think staying a little closer to the "bare metal" is the way to go.. i have no proof to offer that one is actually better than the other

Comment: in my opinion, all course on pluralsigh are so useful especially this one "Entity Framework in the Enterprise"

Comment: @AaronAnodide I know a little about DB from my few projects but none have been in a website project and as big as one I'm working on right now. Also, I think that Dismissile was talking to me when he asked why I think it's "no good".

Comment: I'm not looking to be a professional DB admin in a short period of time. Rather, I'm looking for some common good practices to follow when I try to deploy my project. I want to know what is the right way to "migrate" my project to the *bigger* version of SQL Server. After finding the way, I'll look for details on the way individually.

Comment: @SirwanAfifi Thanks man. I just started watching it. Is there any other course you'd suggest me to watch?

Comment: @AlirezaNoori that course is wonderful, follow that, it will be enough. after that there are some blogs for this issue I'll try to collect and send theme for you.

Comment: @SirwanAfifi I would very much appreciate it. Thank you for all your helps.